Android AGP upgrade returns unexpected error
I have a project with an SAP SDK integration and we needed to update it to a newer version.
This required to increase the target API to 33 but after fixing the compiling errors we receive this

Caused by: android.databinding.tool.processing.ScopedException: [databinding] {"msg":"Unexpected error while processing layout file: fragment_home.xml\n\nPlease file a bug on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component\u003d192721\u0026template\u003d1096850 with a sample project that reproduces the problem.","file":"app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_home.xml","pos":[]}
at android.databinding.tool.util.L.tryToThrowScoped(L.java:98)

The layout files did not change whatsoever. I filled a bug to Google but they do not respond and we run out of time. Any ideas on how to approach this ?
Upgrading for a stable Gradle version will not compile the files, the SAP SDK doesn't yield any errors.

It's the SDK of which SAP software?

SAP BTP SDK for Android

what prevents you from downgrading SAP BTP SDK to the previous version?
